# php definir caminho usando preg_match/preg_replace?

Tags: php

Tenho uma string = "/var/www*/te'st/test.php" e quero poder limpar todos os caracteres especiais, para obter uma string como /var/www/test/test.php

```
$string = "/var/www*/te'st/test.php";
$string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Faltou tornar claro o problema que tem com essa regex neste momento

Comment: @Isac pelo que eu entendi, ele queria a string **/var/www/test/test.php**. Esse regex que ele usou, retorna **varwwwtesttestphp**

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Sim eu também testei e percebi isso, mas quem olha para a pergunta pode não conseguir perceber qual o problema que o autor está a ter. Se ficar na pergunta fica mais claro para todos.

Comment: @Isac sim.. tem rasão!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim:

```
$string = "/var/www*/te'st/test.php";
$string = preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\\.\/]/' , '' , $string );
echo $string;
```

**[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/PvvwHP)**